# fit-content polyfill for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, polyfills

I'm using `fit-content` for a CSS width in my project. But in IE, it doesn't work, according to [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Browser_compatibility) and [this Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width). I'm using `width: fit-content` on a `<div>`. Is there a polyfill for this? If there is another way without a polyfill, I'd gladly accept that.

#### My code (severely stripped down):

```js
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = `${++i} s`}, 1000);
```

```css
#total {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font: 300px "Times New Roman";
  border: 1px solid #000;
  max-width: 88.9%;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content; /* Doesn't work in IE */
}
```

```html
<div id="total">0</div>
```

Comment: You mean `object-fit`? Also you link is to the width property.

Comment: @Dejan.S I mean using `width: fit-content` on a `<div>`. The link is to the width property compatibility table to show that IE doesn't support `fit-content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the width property, by default this property is set to auto.

Then the div will auto increase, code as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function () { document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = (++i) + " s" }, 1000);

</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #total {
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        font: 300px "Times New Roman";
        border: 1px solid #000;
        max-width: 88.9%;
    }
</style>
<div id="total">0</div>
```

The output as below (using IE 11):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width), fit-content is not compatible with IE (or Edge).

Removing "width" didn't work for me, but for anyone else stumbling across this, applying "float: left" to the element works.